# Haskell Stack in Docker: extra-deps not working

Tags: docker, haskell, dockerfile, haskell-stack

I try to compile my program in a docker container with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM haskell:8.4

COPY stack.yaml   /opt/waziup/stack.yaml
COPY foo.cabal /opt/waziup/foo.cabal

WORKDIR /opt/waziup
RUN stack setup
RUN stack install --only-dependencies

COPY .  /opt/waziup
RUN stack install
```

My stack.yaml file is like this:

```
resolver: lts-12.20
extra-deps:
 - servant-flatten-0.2
packages:
 - '.'
```

This works when I type `stack install`. However when I try to compile the docker:

```
$ docker build .

servant-flatten-0.2: download
servant-flatten-0.2: configure
servant-flatten-0.2: build
servant-flatten-0.2: copy/register

...
    /opt/waziup/src/Foo.hs:37:1: error:
        Could not find module ‘Servant.API.Flatten’
        There are files missing in the ‘servant-flatten-0.2’ package,
        try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
        Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Any idea? What happens with the extra-deps package?

Comment: Complementary question: It seems that docker is not very used in the Haskell world (I find only few resources on the Internet on the topic), why is that?

Comment: Typically this error means that some file is corrupt.  Interactively you can delete just that package, but in a Dockerfile it's likely easier to rebuild.  Can you: 1. make sure that `.stack-work` is in your `.dockerignore` 2. `docker build --no-cache .` 3. let us know whether that fixes it.